# Pass data using "data-id" in an anchor tag to a form using jQuery (or some other way)?

Tags: html, jquery, mysql, node.js, forms

I am using node.js with MySQL, handlebars, jwt, and express. The project contains the entities of review, place, and user. I am setting something up kind of like a TripAdvisor site.

The goal is to have a logged-in user click a link to create a review for a place (like a restaurant); that link will take the user to the view of that place in which that user can see the reviews others have left for that place and then the user can then decide to leave their own review for THAT place. That link is the focus. The link takes the user to a review form which will have the user_id and place_id already filled out.

Thus, the user making the review is implied, and the place being reviewed is also implied, which would be from the view in which the user clicked the link. The latter part, which involves passing the place_id of the to the review form is where I am struggling. I've incorporated a login with jwt and auth Middleware, so the user_id part is taken care of for now.

I have tried using jquery, but it doesn't seem to work with res.render, I just click and nothing happens.

```
  $('#add-review-from-place-view').on('click', (evt) => {
    const place_id = $(evt.target).data('id');
    const place_title = $(evt.target).data('title');
    res.render('review/review-add', { place_id: place_id, place_title: place_title} )
    });
  });
```

I am aware of using ajax and rendering a new window location, but I don't know how to pass data with that. I believe it is not possible. Perhaps I am wrong? Looks like this...

```
window.location = new URL(`/review/add/`, window.location.href);
```

This is the html of the the link.

```
 <a href="/review/add" id="add-review-from-place-view" class="btn btn-info" data-id="{{place.place_id}}"
                data-title="{{place.title}}">Review This Place</a>
```

So how would I pass the data-id and the data-title to the form and popular the correct fields? I am a noob, so simplicity is appreciated...thanks for the help.

Comment: Why use the data attributes and not just put those values right in the `href` ?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, passing them as a POST with the id of the place in the URL. I just thought there was another way to do it.